# How to put logs in debug in openAM?

Tags: debugging, openam

How can I debug the `input` and `output request/response` when openAM doing authentication.

Looking forward I want to monitor logs of `SAML request/response` from federated authenticators

I have already tried looking at apache container it is been deployed, but I am not sure that will help.

How can I turn on debug log option so that I can see all the request/response under openAM?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn on "Debug" in admin panel of OpenAM
(Configuration -> Servers and Sites ->  -> General -> Debugging section)

and then select "Debug Level" to "Debug"